# Why is my model distorting when I weight paint?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, file-format, inverse-kinematics

After importing a .OBG file and rigging it, when I weight paint, my model deforms. I use Blender v2.77 .[image]

Comment: Did you use IK (as mentioned in the tags) ?

Comment: yes. I mentioned Inverse kinematics in the tags. since I used inverse kinematic on the legs, the only area that is affected by the deformation. If I paint over the legs, everything deforms.

Comment: This is probably due to that : have a try. Disable the IK and test if the behaviour is the same when painting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have moved some of the bones while in pose mode. While weight painting you are changing how the vertices of the mesh are being influenced by the bones.

To fix this, select the armature and go to pose mode. Then select every bone and press alt+g and alt+r to reset the location and rotation of each bone respectively. (alt+s to reset scale)

Then with your mesh selected and in weight paint mode, you shouldn't see any more deforms while painting because the armature is in its default position.

Comment: I have already tried alt+r and alt+g many times and it has not worked.

Comment: @F.Lu can you add a .blend to your question? That would make it much easier to answer

Comment: I fixed it. The pole angle of the ik bones were at 0 degrees when it should be at 90 degrees. I changed it, so thank you for helping me